# JQuery .append() Separate Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I've made a script which adds an image and a textbox to a canvas. In order for the textbox to appear over the image, I need to apply CSS to the image. Therefore I made to separate divs, `<img>` for the image and `<text>` for the text.

This creates two problems. When I fist add the image and the text the two elements are considered separate and I can only drag either the image or the text, rather than the two elements at the same time. Furthermore, when I add another image and another textbox the two don't appear on top of each other, rather the text is spawned next to the textbox and the  image next to the image.

So my question is this. Is it possible to consolidate these two elements into one and when spawned make them do so, make them do it the same way every time?

Here is my Javascript I made for it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#img").draggable();
$("#text").draggable();
});

function addEvent() {
$("#img").append("<img src='Sticky_Note.png'</a>")
$("#text").append(" <textarea name='comments' x-webkit-speech='x-webkit-speech'style='width:380px;height:300px; background: none; border:none; font-size:24px; color:#0033FF;font-family:comic sans ms' />")

}
```

Should this not be enough information (I'm n00btastic, sorry), I 've attactched a bleeding edge link [here.](http://www.bookofsam.com/corkboard/ScriptDIV2.html)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `<img src='Sticky_Note.png'</a>` is invalid HTML and does not make much sense anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the issue with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a wrapper `<div>` around your image and text elements, e.g. `<div id="#wrapper">`. Then you can do the following:

```
$('#wrapper').draggable();
```

Your addEvent code would look like:

```
function addEvent() {
    $("#wrapper").append("<img src='Sticky_Note.png'</a>");
    $("#wrapper").append(" <textarea name='comments' x-webkit-speech='x-webkit-speech'style='width:380px;height:300px; background: none; border:none; font-size:24px; color:#0033FF;font-family:comic sans ms' />");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a few issues with your implementation, I'll ignore the basic document issues as I figure you were putting together a quick example :)

When you append a new 'note' it's not individually movable, it's the container that is movable so they just stack up as you're only adding more content to the corkboard container, ie: another textarea/image, then another textarea/image.

I've put up a solution on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/8PHq7hPM), feel free to have a look, hopefully it helps point you in the right direction.

Actually, i'll embed it too, for posterity

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #corkboard { position: relative; }
        #corkboard textarea { position: absolute; width: 380px; height: 300px; top: 100px; left: 60px; background: none; border: none; font-size: 24px; color: #03f; font-family: 'comic sans ms', serif; }
        #corkboard img { position: absolute; }

        .corkboard-item {
            position: absolute;
            float: left;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            // Create our corkboard item
            //
            $corkboard_item = $( '<div></div>' );
            $corkboard_item
                .addClass( 'corkboard-item' )
                .append( '<img src="http://www.bookofsam.com/corkboard/Sticky_Note.png" />' )
                .append( '<textarea name="comments" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech">Enter your note</textarea>' );

            // Counter goodness
            $x = 1;


            // Make sure the one we click is always at the top
            //
            $( 'img, textarea' ).live( 'click', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $( '.corkboard-item' ).each( function() {
                    $( this ).css({ 'z-index':1 });
                });

                $( this )
                    .parent()
                    .css({
                        'z-index':2
                    })
            });


            // Add one when we click the button
            //
            $( 'a.add-item' ).live( 'click', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var item = $corkboard_item.clone();
                $( item )
                    .find( 'textarea' )
                    .attr({
                        'name' : ( 'comment-' + $x )
                    });

                $x++;

                $("#corkboard").append( $( item ).draggable() );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>CORKBOARD TEST - 0.8.555 </p>

    <a href="#" class="add-item"><img src='http://www.bookofsam.com/corkboard/Note_Scale.png' align="right" /></a>

    <div id="corkboard"></div>
</html>
```

Thinking about it, I should've really put the 'note' image as a background image on the 'corkboard-item'.

:)

nbsp;